# How to reference a variable in `` javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

So I'm using testcafe and I and declaring a test like this

```
test .page `myreallylongurl` ('check email', async  t => {
    //my test for this URL hear


})
```

but I don't want to do that because I will not be able to see the names of all my test what I would like to do something along the lines of

```
const url ="myreallylongurl"
    test .page `$url` ('check email', async  t => {
        //my test for this URL hear

    })
```

But am unsure how to do this and could not find anything about it. Thanks!

Comment: Google string interpolation, or template literals in JS; the syntax should be `\`${ url }\``

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: thanks @Pop-A-Stash thats what I was loking for

Answer (score 4):

This library is (ab)using [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) to call the function. You can try using a substitution

```
const url = "myreallylongurl"
test.page `${url}` ('check email', async t => {});
```

or call the function explicitly with an array literal:

```
const url = "myreallylongurl"
test.page([url])('check email', async t => {});
```

Comment: Which one, both of them?